# Inno Setup - wildcard and specific "Source" covering same file - which instruction takes priority?

Tags: inno-setup

Suppose I have:

```
[Files]
Source: *.*; DestDir: {app}; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: address.txt; DestDir: {app}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist
```

Which takes precedence and is the behavior defined? I would think that either the specific or last listed of the two overrides depending on the internal logic, but would be nice if he behavior was defined.

---

If they both get executed (as an answer indicates), I will instead need to use something like:

```
[Files]
Source: *.*; DestDir: {app}; Flags: recursesubdirs; Excludes: "address.txt"
Source: address.txt; DestDir: {app}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (almost) nothing special happening.

Both rules are processed, in the definition order, as any other rules.

- First the `address.txt` is installed by the first mask rule.
- And then the second specific rule is processed (but in this specific case, it does nothing due to the `onlyifdoesntexist` flag).

```
2017-05-28 15:39:52.678   -- File entry --
2017-05-28 15:39:52.678   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\My Program\address.txt
2017-05-28 15:39:52.678   Time stamp of our file: 2017-05-28 15:39:20.000
2017-05-28 15:39:52.678   Installing the file.
2017-05-28 15:39:52.678   Successfully installed the file.
2017-05-28 15:39:52.678   -- File entry --
2017-05-28 15:39:52.678   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\My Program\address.txt
2017-05-28 15:39:52.678   Time stamp of our file: 2017-05-28 15:39:20.000
2017-05-28 15:39:52.678   Dest file exists.
2017-05-28 15:39:52.678   Skipping due to "onlyifdoesntexist" flag.
```

---

The only special thing happening with these two rules, is that Inno Setup identifies that a  same file (`address.txt`) is being referred to twice, so it stores the file only once to the installer.

You will see only one record for `address.txt` in the compiler output:

```
   Compressing: C:\source\address.txt
```

But that would happen with any rules (even two specific rules) referring to the same file. So it's not about wildcard vs. specific rule.

---

When you [decompile the installer](https://innounp.sourceforge.net/), you will see that the wildcard rule is actually expanded to individual rules by the compiler.

So you effectively get this:

```
[Files]
Source: "???\address.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; 
Source: "???\address.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist
```